# Split arrays into separate strings

Tags: php

I've got an array see here:

```
foreach ($fonts as $font) {

        $html .= '<option value="'. $font['name'] .''. $font['font'] .''. $font['css'] .'"' . selected( $layout_options['h1-font'], ''. $font['name'] .''. $font['font'] .''. $font['css'] .'', false) . '>' . __( ''. $font['name'] .'' ) . '</option>';

            $html.= $font['font'];
        $html .= '</option>';
    }
```

The var_dump results for it are here:

Using

```
var_dump($layout_options['h1-font']
```

I get the results

```
string(85) "Lobster@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster);'Lobster', cursive"
```

That array consists of the following variables

```
'. $font['name'] .''. $font['font'] .''. $font['css'] .'
```

I need to separate them, ideally I would like to use

```
$layout_options['hi-font-css']
```

How can I do this?

UPDATE:

Hopefully it will explain it more if I post all the code.

Here is my function, i'll go back to the original code as this worked slightly better.

```
function span_font_callback() {
$layout_options = (array) get_option( 'layout_options' );
$fonts = get_fonts();
$current = 'arial';

if ( isset( $layout_options['span-font'] ) )
    $current = $layout_options['span-font'];

?>
    <select name="layout_options[span-font]">
      <option value="default">Please select an option</option>
      <?php foreach( $fonts as $key => $font ): ?>
        <option <?php if($key == $current) echo "SELECTED"; ?> value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $font['name']; ?></option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="layout_options[span_font_size]" size="6" value="<?php echo $layout_options['span_font_size']; ?>" placeholder="Size"/>
    <input type="text" name="layout_options[span_font_colour]" size="6" value="<?php echo $layout_options['span_font_colour']; ?>" placeholder="Colour"/>

<?php   
}
```

Here's the get_fonts() function

```
function get_fonts() {
$fonts = array(
    'arial' => array(
        'name' => 'Arial',
        'font' => '',
        'css' => "'Arial', sans-serif"
    ),
    'Montez' => array(
        'name' => 'Montez',
        'font' => '@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montez);',
        'css' => "'Montez', cursive"
    ),
    'Open Sans' => array(
        'name' => 'Open Sans',
        'font' => '@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);',
        'css' => "'Open Sans', sans-serif"
    ),
    'ubuntu' => array(
        'name' => 'Ubuntu',
        'font' => '@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu);',
        'css' => "'Ubuntu', sans-serif"
    ),
    'lobster' => array(
        'name' => 'Lobster',
        'font' => '@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster);',
        'css' => "'Lobster', cursive"
    )
);

return apply_filters( 'get_fonts', $fonts );
```

}

And here's my stylesheet.php

```
<?php $layout_options       = get_option ( 'layout_options' ); ?>

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster);
.hero_text {
text-align: right;
padding-left: 5px;
display: inline;
float: right;
clear: both;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
font-family: <?php echo $layout_options['h1-font']; ?>;
font-size: <?php echo $layout_options['h1_font_size']; ?>;
color: <?php echo $layout_options['h1_font_colour']; ?>;
line-height: 20px;
}
```

I need to replace the

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster);
```

with the font array so that when my drop down lists changes, it will change that line to match the font. I need to use something like below but specifically to the array name, css and font?

```
<?php echo $layout_options['h1-font-']; ?>;
```

Hope this yeps you more?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Where are you setting `$layout_options`? What do you want to use as the delimiter to split it up?

Comment: Even after reading it 4 times I absolutely don't understand what your question is... What is your current array and how do you want to transform it?

Comment: Why do you concatenate `''` between each element of `$font`? That doesn't do anything. Just write `$font['name'] . $font['font'] . $font['css']`.

Comment: Hi, very sorry for the lack of input, I have updated the post now to give your the whole code to help you understand what i'm trying to do, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just before concatenating your `$html`string do the following:

```
$layout_options['hi-font-css'] = $font['name'] . $font['font'] . $font['css'];
```

Thus the whole code would be:

```
foreach ($fonts as $font) {
        $layout_options['hi-font-css'] = $font['name'] . $font['font'] . $font['css'];
        $html .= '<option value="'. $layout_options['hi-font-css'] .'"' . selected( $layout_options['h1-font'], ''. $layout_options['hi-font-css'] .'', false) . '>' . __( ''. $font['name'] .'' ) . '</option>';

        $html.= $font['font'];
        $html .= '</option>';
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be assigning to `$layout_options`, not `$font`?

Comment: Indeed, my bad. I will fix this . EDIT: fixed

Comment: Although that looks much cleaner than my code, I need the array to show something like ["h1-font-name"]=> string(85) "Lobster"
 ["h1-font-font"]=> string(85) "@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster);"
 ["h1-font-css"]=> string(85) "'Lobster', cursive"